# Who built all the pathways and stuff in the Batcave?

Tags: dc, batman

I know that the actual cave that became the Batcave was natural. However, all the different versions of the Batcave have a bunch of complex constructions such as roads, platforms and modified water-ways. Who built all these? And how was it kept secret?

I'm fine with answers from all different versions and continuities of Batman.

This is related but different to [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9813/how-was-the-batcave-built-in-secret).

[image: Batcave image 1]

[image: Batcave image 2]

[image: Batcave image 3]

[image: Batcave image 4]

Comment: http://www.cracked.com/article_18968_5-reasons-there-must-be-corpses-buried-under-batcave.html

Comment: I think this question just barely avoids being a duplicate of the linked question.  Well played.

Comment: In Nolan's Batman, as well as in "Gotham", the construction started with other Waynes. In the former, it was an unusually literal stop on the underground railroad, and the latter(which seems to include more construction/technology) it was part of Papa Wayne's still ambiguous secret life. That said, this doesn't tell us who gave the place it's full Bat-makeover.

Answer (score 4):

In Batman Begins, the implication is that Bruce (and Alfred) used the construction of an additional set of foundations as a ruse to *improve* his underground base:

> **Bruce Wayne:** Rebuild it. Just the way it was, brick for brick.
>   **Alfred Pennyworth:** *Just* the way it was, sir?
>   **Bruce Wayne:** Yeah. Why?
>   **Alfred Pennyworth:** I thought this might be a good opportunity for improving the foundations.
>   **Bruce Wayne:** [In the south-east corner?](http://www.metacafe.com/watch/an-1bLvn2nb4h7bb/batman_begins_2005_ruins/)
>   **Alfred Pennyworth:** Precisely, sir.

Given the layout of the Batcave I see no good reason to assume that the contractors would have thought that they were building anything other than an oversized underground parking garage for Bruce Wayne, the notably eccentric billionaire and sport-car enthusiast. I'm guessing they were also made to sign really restrictive non-disclosure agreements.

Comment: Did Wayne get a building permit for those improvements? Was it inspected by the city building inspectors? Did it result in a big jump in the valuation of Wayne's property on the real estate tax rolls?

Comment: @user14111 - Assuming Gotham city is in New Jersey; 1) He didn't get a permit. It was constructed by him and Alfred. 2) It has never been inspected by the City Ordinance, hence it would fall within New Jersey's "illegal basement" legislation, even if it's wholly on Bruce Wayne's property. 3) The size would have no impact on the tax he pays since it's entirely contained within his property lines. Warning. I am not a lawyer. If you're planning to construct a secret underground base, consult a property specialist and a realtor first.

Answer (score 1):

If you can build a deck by yourself; you can build a scaffolding by yourself. Through the comics history the cave is often depicted as either heavily built up possibly using concrete or metal or very natural with a series of machinery integrated into it.

Being realistic. How do you fabricate a super high tech headquarters and disguise your activities as general business? Pre-fabricated building eliminates most of the guess work. One note in DC was the Bruce Wayne hired a small team of builders under the guise of building a top secret defense related facility like an underground bunker; where as the location was kept secret even to the construction workers and largely transported and kept in the dark as to the location of where they were building. They didn't have to build anything bat related, just the general structure, in pre fabricated components Bruce and Alfred could have installed the rest.